# Ansible shell comand with root elevation

Tags: shell, command-line, ansible, root, elevation

I use the following command to search in my machines a specific data:

```
ansible -i [inventory_name].inventory [inventory group] -m shell -a "grep 'PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

but now, I need elevate the user to root (to see the content of the file). It is possible in this same command line? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ansible --help` suggests:

> Privilege Escalation Options:
>
> ```
> -b, --become        run operations with become (does not imply password
>                     prompting)
> ```

Comment: How come? I use it everyday.

Comment: I use: 
  ansible -vvvv -i totalv1_PAC.inventory serverstest -m shell -a -b "grep 'PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"

Comment: This way you pass shell string as value to `-b` parameter instead of `-a`. Try: `ansible -i totalv1_PAC.inventory serverstest -m shell -b -a "grep 'PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"`

Comment: ansible -i totalv1_PAC.inventory serverstest -m shell -b -a "grep 'PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]

ansible: error: no such option: -b

Probably, I need specify "-b" parameter in any place...I don´t know really...

Comment: what Ansible version do you use?

Comment: ansible 1.7.2 and Python 2.7.9, I try to update to the last and then follow your advices. Thank you

Comment: I´ve update ansible to 2.3.0.0, but with your comand ansible -i totalv1_PAC.inventory serverstest -m shell -b -a "grep 'PermitRootLogin' /etc/ssh/sshd_config" obtain the following message: Missing sudo password